Esistono nomi comuni nella lingua italiana per distinguere quello che in inglese viene chiamato "monkeys" e "apes"?
Ho l'impressione che in italiano, sia apes sia monkeys sono chiamati con il nome comune scimmie, ma forse sono sbagliata. In catalano, per esempio, apes è tradotto come simis e monkeys come mones. Els simis in catalano o the apes in inglese a giorno d'oggi comprendono unicamente i gibboni, gli oranghi, i bonobo, gli scimpanzé, i gorilla e gli homo sapiens, e non sono mones in catalano o monkeys in inglese.
Esistono nomi comuni nella lingua italiana usati per distinguere questi due taxa? Ho cercato sulla Wikipedia, ma gli articoli corrispondenti mi sono sembrati di una grande confusione.
Nella traduzione all'italiano fatta da Salvatore Romano del libro Origins of Human Communication di Michael Tomasello, che ho a casa, l'espressione monkeys and apes è tradotta come scimmie e grandi scimmie. Questa traduzione mi sembra quantomeno curiosa per due ragioni. La prima è che, se le grandi scimmie sono anche scimmie, non mi sembra abbia molto senso dire scimmie e grandi scimmie. La seconda è che nello stesso libro si usa grandi scimmie come traduzione di great apes. Tradurre sia apes (dove sono inclusi i lesser apes) sia great apes come grandi scimmie mi sembra crei confusione. Va bene, quello che è successo è che ho letto alcune pagine del libro in italiano e non capivo nulla. Ma, per fortuna, alcune di queste pagine dell'originale in inglese si possono leggere su Google Libri.

Ciò che hai letto conferma quindi ancora di più, secondo me, che in italiano non ci sono parole più specifiche, equivalenti a mones/simis e simili coppie in altri linguaggi.

In contesti non tecnici a volte ce la si può cavare con forme alterate (scimmioni, scimmiette) per rendere almeno in parte qualcosa degli aspetti connotativi delle due parole inglesi.

Da ignorante, direi che "apes" sono le scimmie antropomorfe, ossia quelle più simili all'uomo (oranghi, bonobo, scimpanzé, gorilla). "Monkey" è invece un termine generico che indica tutti gli animali appartenenti alla categoria, un po' come "scimmia" in italiano si può usare genericamente per indicare qualsiasi membro, dai gorilla al tamarin al macaco, etc.
EDIT: basandomi anche su quanto detto da @DaG nei commenti, credo che in italiano non esistano termini precisi corrispondenti a monkey/ape mones/micos/simis monos/simios etc., o se esistono sono molto specialistici e/o poco comuni (e io non li conosco). Direi che il meglio che si può fare in italiano è quindi usare perifrasi come "scimmie/primati antropomorfe/i [senza coda]", "scimmie medio/piccole con coda" ed altre simili descrizioni a seconda del contesto.

È vero che monkey si può usare anche per designare i primati in generale ma il primo significato, quello pertinente quando si distinguono apes e monkeys è “a small to medium-sized primate that typically has a long tail, most kinds of which live in trees in tropical countries”.

E infatti ho detto "da ignorante" :-) Grazie

Grazie, @persson: ho aggiunto una frase al mio post per cercare di spiegarmi meglio.

@DaG: Non credo che monkeys si usi per tutti i primati. Per esempio, non credo che i lemuri siano considerati monkeys.

Credo che, in inglese come in altre lingue, "monkey" possa avere sia un'accezione specifica che una generica, vedi ad esempio l'oxford dictionary https://www.oed.com/dictionary/monkey_n?tab=meaning_and_use ("Also more generally: any higher primate, including the apes as well as the true monkeys."). Imparo inoltre da quella definizione che anticamente era "ape" il termine generico.

Va bene, @persson: allora nella mia domanda mi riferisco a "true monkeys".

Ok, in tutti i casi credo di non dovere aggiungere nulla alla mia risposta dopo l'edit.
